# Basic Scala: Methods holding parameters?

Tags: scala, methods

I am reading the book Programming in Scala and in chapter 10 I had to write:

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  def height: Int = contents.length
  def width: Int = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}

class ArrayElement(conts: Array[String]) extends Element {
  def contents: Array[String] = conts
}
```

but the concept I don't catch here is how can I define a method that is holding a variable? As far as I know, methods *return a value*, it can be a computed value or an instance variable directly, but they can't *hold a value*. Am I forgetting a basic concept about the programming language that applies here too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
abstract class Foo { def bar: Int }
class Baz(val bar: Int) extends Foo
```

In Scala, you can implement methods by creating member variables with same name and same type. The compiler then adds a corresponding getter-method automatically.

The member variable and the getter-method are still two different things, but you don't see much difference syntactically: when you try to access it, its both just `foo.bar`, regardless of whether `bar` is a method or a member variable.

In your case

```
def contents: Array[String] = conts
```

is just an ordinary method that returns an array, an equivalent way to write the same thing would be

```
def contents: Array[String] = {
  return conts
}
```

Since the array is mutable, you can in principle use this method to modify entries of your array, but the method itself is really just a normal method, it doesn't "hold" anything, it just returns reference to your array.

Edit: I've just noticed that `conts` is actually not a member variable. However, its still captured in the definition of the `contents` method by the closure-mechanism.

Comment: I know, they share the same namespace. My question was regarding this method definition on the sub-class: def contents: Array[String] = conts . How can the method 'contents' hold a value? (Maybe you are actually answering my question but I don't see the point)

Comment: I added an edit. Hope it's clearer now. Your method does not "hold" anything. It just returns the reference to your array.

Comment: Oh! sry, I have just realized that conts is an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for improving your answer anyway :)

Comment: Ok, It's actually even somewhat more subtle... `conts` is not a member variable, but its captured by the closure mechanism when you define your `contents` method. This is almost the same as being a private member variable (in JavaScript, they even use a similar closure mechanism to hide private variables), but it's not exactly the same.